# Using Robot Framework's Process lib, curl -c will not create a cookie

Tags: curl, cookies, robotframework

Using the Process lib, I have created the following:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation

Library    Process
Library    OperatingSystem

*** Test Case ***
Test Case
    Start Sesh

*** Keyword ***
Start Sesh
    ${Authenticate}=    Run Process  curl  -c cookie.txt  -d j_username\=regression1%40att&j_password\=TCpass1234&submit\=Login  https://api.company.com/j_spring_security_check
```

Running the curl command on a command line produces a cookie titled cookie.txt in the working directory.

Running the command in Robot Framework for some reason will not even create the text file, let alone populate it with a session.

**Goal**: I am trying to get curl to create a cookie in RF the same way it would in a command line scenario.

**EDIT**: I may have solved the issue by using shell=True. Stay posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Here is the answer if you want to run CURL with Robot Framework:

**Prerequisites:**

- Process Library
- Curl for Windows
- Set Curl.exe to your Path var in windows
- Also know that I got this to work with a REST API

**Code:**

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation

Library    Process

*** Variables ***
${COOKIE}            C:/sq_automation/cookie.txt

*** Keywords ***
Start API Session
    ${Authenticate}    Run Process    curl -i -c ${COOKIE} -d "j_username\=regression1%40att&j_password\=TCpass1234&submit\=Login https://api.website.com/j_spring_security_check"    shell=True    alias=Auth    cwd=C:/sq_automation
    Should Contain    ${Authenticate.stdout}    HTTP/1.1 302 Found
    ${result}    Get Process Result    Auth    rc=True    stdout=True    stderr=True

API POST
    ${Login}    Run Process    curl -i -b ${COOKIE} -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d "{\\"password\\":\\"${PASSWORD}\\",\\"username\\":\\"${USERID}\\"}" https://api.touchcommerce.com/engagementAPI/v1/agent/login?output\=json    shell=True    alias=Login    cwd=C:/sq_automation
    Should Contain    ${Login.stdout}    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    ${result}    Get Process Result    Login    rc=True    stdout=True    stderr=True
    Get Registered ID    ${Login.stdout}
```

I could only get this to work with shell=True. It is necessary that you write the curl command with only one space between arguments and the proper character escapes for backslashes, and equal signs.