# Curl command not working properly on Robot Framework with Process Library

Tags: curl, request, robotframework

I have to program an automated test for a POST request, i'm using curl command because said post needs a CSV file to include or exclude fields to search, the thing is that, although the following command works fine on Ubuntu terminal, in Robot Framework this happens:

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

My Robot Framework code is (it's just a test to familiarize with the method):

```
*** Settings ***
Library     Process

*** Variables ***
${command}  curl -X POST "http://10.0.0.85:7173/v1/performance/custom/games?gameId=2019101308&isExclusion=false&teamId=2510" -H  "accept: */*" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@file;type=text/csv"s

*** Test Cases ***
Test Get endpoint
    ${test}=    run process     ${command}
```

The command is generated by Swagger (i do my manual tests there), i dont know where i can be failing, the file is in the same directory as the .robot file

Comment: What else is different between these two environments? Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: yeap, both commands are run in the same path with the same files, i don't know what can be causing this issue

Comment: You could also try to use [RequestsLibrary](http://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/doc/RequestsLibrary.html).

Comment: If you look at the documentation of the `Run Process` keyword, you will see that it will expect command and arguments. Now, in your code, you are essentially just passing in the command and RF thinks that your `${command}` is a command, which it aint, as you probably dont have a script/binary/executable called `curl -X POST "http://10.0.0.85:7173/ etcetcetc.....`.

Comment: Similar question was asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48471570/737440).